# Enable click in Data grid Cell elements

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

Here is the cell in a Data grid cell, I am trying to add Tooltip and onClick for Red, Yellow and Gray elements Some how onClick and tooltip both are not working

```
<DataGridPro
        {...data}
        initialState={data}
        headerHeight={36}
        disableSelectionOnClick
        slots={{
          toolbar: CustomToolbar,
        }}
        hideFooter
        sx={{
          '.MuiDataGrid-iconButtonContainer': {
            visibility: 'visible',
          },
          '.MuiDataGrid-sortIcon': {
            opacity: 'inherit !important',
          },
        }}
        sortModel={sortModel}
        onSortModelChange={(model) => setSortModel(model)}
      />
```

[Cell Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n5uJ.png)
I tried above code no clue